# how to implement sass code

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to incorporate this sass code,but it is not happening, please let me know the process how i can implement it.

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

h1 { color:#0ec3f7;}

$divColor : #f8f9be;
$borderStyle : dotted;
$width : 700px;
$height : 200px;

#first {background-color:divColor; border:1px borderStyle #F00; width:width; height:height;}
```

This the html file

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>    
<title>css-saas-less</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sasstemp.scss"  />    
</head>    
<body>   
<h1> CSS preprocessors </h1>

<div id="first">welcome to sass.....
</div></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have to use app to transfer your sass code to css

f.e. 
http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/ (free, windows) OR
http://compass.handlino.com/ (windows)

and your code should look like this

**stylesheet.sass:**

```
$divColor: #f8f9be
$borderStyle: dotted
$width: 700px
$height: 200px

#first 
    background-color: $divColor
    border: 1px $borderStyle #F00
    width: $width
    height: $height
```

( *no {} or ;* )

for more informations visit http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html

or this awesome video tutorial from Jeffrey Way: http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/mastering-sass/

Comment: Note that you can also use the [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) command-line tool, which is, i believe, what most front-end developers use.

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sasstemp.scss"  />
```

this suppose to be like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sasstemp.css"  />
```

else
fist of all you need ruby installed on your system then you need to install sass gem.
Take a look at http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html for assistance.